# lwIP on Stellaris 32-bit microcontroller - Secure Login

Tags: security, authentication, microcontroller, lwip

I wish to use my Stellaris LM3S8962 microcontroller as a bridge between internet and a bunch of sensors. I will be using Zigbee nodes for communication from the sensors to the microcontroller. I have been able to use the lwIP TCP/IP stack (for LM3S8962) to access HTML pages stored in the controller's flash.

Now, I want to add a secure login system for the same. What I basically want is that - when I enter the IP of the controller in the browser, it should prompt me for a username and a password. I want to make this system as secure as possible using the lwIP TCP/IP stack.

FYI, the stack does not support PHP or any other scripts. CGI feature (in C) is supported but I don't know how to implement the security part. Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two ways you could implement user authentication over HTTP on your platform:

- "classic" Basic HTTP authentication (see RFC2616 for exact specification),
- a login form, creating a session ID, and returning that to the browser, to be stored either in a cookie, or in the URL.

Basic HTTP authentication works by you inserting a check into your web page serving routine, to see if there is an Authorization HTTP header. If there is, you should decode it (see the RFC), and check the specified username/password. If the credentials are ok, then proceed with the web page serving. If the credentials are incorrect, or in case there is no Authorization header, you should return a 401 error code. The browser will then prompt the user for the credentials. This solution is rather simple, and you'll get the browser login dialog, not a nice HTML page. Also, the microcontroller will have to check the credentials for every page request.

Authentication via a login form works by your server maintaining a list of properly authenticated user sessions (probably in memory), and checking the request against this list. Upon loggin in, a unique, random ID should be generated for that session, and the session data should be entered into your list. The new session ID should be returned to the browser to be included in upcoming HTTP requests. You may choose the session ID to be put into a browser cookie, or you can embed it into the URL, as a URL parameter (?id=xxxxx). The URL parameter is embedded by sending a 302 Redirection response to the browser with the new URL. If you want the cookie solution, you can send the response to the login request with a Set-Cookie HTTP response header. In the login form solution, the actual credentials (username/password) are only checked once, at login. After that, only the session ID is checked against the list of active sessions. The session ID has to be extracted from the requests for every web page serving (from the URL, or from the Cookie HTTP header). Also, you'll have to implement some kind of session timeout, both as a security measure, and to put bounds to the size of the list of active sessions.

Now comes the harder part: in both solutions, the username/password travels in some requests (in every request for the Basic HTTP authentication, and in the login page POST for the login form solution), and can be extracted from the network traffic. Also, information neccessary to hijack the session is present in every request in both solutions. If this is a problem (the system works on a freely accessible LAN segment, or over network links beyond your control), you'll probably need SSL to hide these sensitive data. How to get a reasonable SSL implementation for your platform, that's another question.